# range input change event not fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery and jquery mobile to catch a change event. I am using this html and jquery code:

html:

```
<input type="range" name="someName" min="0" max="10"/>
```

jquery:

```
$('input[type="range"]').change(function(){
    alert('asdasd');
});
```

when I change the input attribute to name it works fine. Like this:

```
$('input[name="range"]').change(function(){
        alert('asdasd');
});
```

I don't know why the event is not being cached.
Thanks

Comment: Works for me in Chrome – http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/dmZNn/. Are you sure you're testing in a browser, supporting 'range' type for input?

Comment: Worked on IE9! Thanks @spliter for jsfiddle. :)

Comment: change only fires when you click somewhere outside the changes element

Comment: Not really, @ParvSharma. 'change' happens when a form field value changes. You don't need to click somewhere else on the page for this to happen. Especially with 'range' input

Comment: what do u mean by "event is not being cached." do u mean not fired???

Comment: I am using latest chrome

Comment: I mean there is no event after changing

Comment: @spliter Text inputs generally don't fire the `change` event until they lose focus (provided the value has changed), but other types (radio, checkbox, etc) fire it as soon as their `checked`/`selected` state changes.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist that's right. And this means that 'change' is not necessarily fired when one clicks outside of an element. Tabbing away from a text field fires up 'change'. But there was no click. Simply speaking 'change' happens right before 'focusout' (everywhere except Firefox) or 'blur' (in Firefox) happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use change event, use slidestart or slidestop.

More info: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/slider/events.html

Here's an example I have created few days ago: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PzTeX/

```
$("input#europe, input#us, input#uk, input#japan").live("slidestop", function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. Maybe you are calling the jquery before the element is loaded. Is it wrapped in document.ready? Are you using a non-html5 browser?

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="range"]').change(function(){
        alert('asdasd');
    });
});
```

Comment: it is wrapped with document.ready and I am using latest Chrome. Tried on all the popular browsers (firefox, explorer, Opera etc.)

Comment: nope, I copied the code @spliter gave from Fiddle and it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

'input[type="range"]' don't trigger `change` when `Emulate touch screen` is true on then Chrome